# How to convert spring based java project into maven projects?

Tags: spring, maven

I am planning to convert my spring based java project into maven project, so in this conversation what kind of project structure and configuration I should follow

Comment: The standard maven project structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out the dependencies of your project and it would be better to unify them through either ready made BOM or you create your own
[Maven BOM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies)
To facilitate code organization, it is advisable to use multi-module projects 
[Maven multi-modules tutorial](http://www.codetab.org/apache-maven-tutorial/maven-multi-module-project/)